# Jquery this function not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement `$(this)` in my website to make every clicked object animate. Obviously I can write a function for each item but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with `$(this)`. So far it's not working properly.

```
<div class="prod">
  <div id="checking">
    <img src="bandImages/chkg.jpg" />
    <div id="debit">
      <img src="bandImages/debit.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
  $(".prod").click(function() {
    $(".this").animate({
      width: '140px',
      height: '140px',
      opacity: '1.0'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's funny how users keep answering questions (without extra details) inspite of knowing that the solution is already posted. Also, this should be closed as a simple typo error.

Comment: you said $(this) in not working and your implementing as $(.this) ..why ??

Comment: @Mr.Alien  : its like rat race for reputation points .. funny indeed

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this)
```

not

```
$(".this")
```

`.this` is a class name, it doesn't exist in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

change .this to this.

```
<script>
$(".prod").click(
function(){
   $(this).animate({width: '140px', height: '140px', opacity: '1.0'});

}

);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

used to `$(this)` not `$('.this')`  and used to **[.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

as like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.prod').on('click', function(){
  $(this).animate({width: '140px', height: '140px', opacity: '1.0'});
  
  })
 
});
```

```css
.prod{border:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod">

   <div id="checking">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76e03db06bb6dcf24f95bf4d354486db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />

 <div id="debit">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76e03db06bb6dcf24f95bf4d354486db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">

    </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery object `$(this)`, `$(".this")` will be a jquery object of all the elements having class `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` not use `$('this')`.

you are used.

```
$(".this").animate({width: '140px',height: '140px',opacity: '1.0'});
```

it's wrong. wright way below

```
$(this).animate({width: '140px',height: '140px',opacity: '1.0'});
```